# How do PHP compare arrays

Tags: php

Considering two PHP arrays with a single element:

```
$left = array(
  230985 => "/A/B/C/D"
);
```

and

```
$right = array(
  223372 => "/A/B/C"
);
```

On this statement:

```
if($left <= $right)
```

How do PHP will compare these arrays to determine an order between them?

Comparing two strings will use an alphabetical order, but what's the behavior for arrays?

Comment: You're using invalid operator for comparison. Look at the array operators, http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

Comment: first thing is when you using relational operator in if statement it produces eight er true or false value .we can't apply relational operator to strings in php..
better to make any other logic for this problem

Comment: The [PHP Docs](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) exactly have a very good explanation of how standard comparison operators work with arrays (see `Example #2 Transcription of standard array comparison` on the linked page); and it entails matching up keys.... your keys are totally different, so no comparison can be made, so you actually get a null return, which equates to a false

Comment: Thanks Mark for this explanation! It also explains why `$left <= $right` and `$right <= $left` always returns false

Comment: Yes, give them matching keys, and you'll get a different result

Answer (score 1):

It won't compare, it will return `false`

Try:

```
var_dump($left <= $right);
```

Result:

```
bool(false)
```

Comment: But false could also mean that `$left` is "greater" than `$right`, therefore it compares it...and that's the question here: how.

Comment: @nv1t Try to turn it around `var_dump($left >= $right);` it will still return false

Comment: I know this comparison is definitely not the correct way to compare arrays. My question is why PHP returning false every time, what PHP is currently comparating? As both comparisons returns false, did PHP just failed at comparing these two arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the function available in php  :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php